# How can I config in Apache httpd.conf to disguise different homepage files in the same folder as if they were in different folders?

Tags: apache, config, virtual

I have a project whose folder structure is like this:

```
/www
    /img
    /css
    /js
    /templates
    index1.html
    index2.html
    index3.html
```

As the above, I have three homepage files. Because they have a lot of common parts, they are in one project folder. So in fact, they belong to one project. But I want people to visit this site with such urls:

```
http://www.servername.com/project1/
http://www.servername.com/project2/
http://www.servername.com/project3/
```

as if they were three different projects. Because I don't want to show people that this is just one project. I want them look like in three different projects, and the three homepage files had the same name (index.html).

So I have to config virtual directories in the `httpd.conf` file. I put three `<IfModule dir_module>` nodes in the `httpd.conf` file, but it seems not work:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index1.html

    Alias /project1/ "E:/www/"
    <Directory "E:/www/">
        ......
    </Directory>
</IfModule>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index2.html

    Alias /project2/ "E:/www/"
    <Directory "E:/www/">
        ......
    </Directory>
</IfModule>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index3.html

    Alias /project3/ "E:/www/"
    <Directory "E:/www/">
        ......
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Then how can I do to achieve this purpose?

Comment: Thank you! But I can't modify the host name, it's fixed. I can only modify the directory part of URLs.

Comment: Not talking about the systems host name, but the virtual host names in your http server configuration. Since you have access to that configuration you certainly can define those as you like. The only thing you need apart from that is a "wildcard DNS resolution" for the A record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best probably would be to configure separate host names, actually, so `project1.example.com`, `project2.example.com` and so on. You can configure those as virtual hosts in your http servers configuration. The only thing you need apart from that is a "wildcard DNS resolution" for the A record.

But if you really want to use paths for separation, then easiest would be to use a symbolic link in side the file system, which would allow for separate configurations for those. Since it looks like you are on MS-Windows you do not have that option though, that system does not offer such feature. So you have to try a work around...

Since you can have only one `DirectoryIndex` directive per folder your approach won't work. But since your "projects" apparently consist of only a single static html file, why not simply change the `Alias` directives accordingly?

```
Alias /project1 "E:/www/index1.html"
Alias /project2 "E:/www/index2.html"
Alias /project3 "E:/www/index3.html"
DocumentRoot "E:/www"
<Directory "E:/www/">
    # Whatever options you need for the common folder
</Directory>
```

---

An alternative would be to use "internal rewriting". You need the rewriting module (mod_rewrite) to be loaded and active for that, obviously. Then you can do something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?project1 /index1.html [END]
RewriteRule ^/?project2 /index2.html [END]
RewriteRule ^/?project3 /index3.html [END]
DocumentRoot "E:/www"
<Directory "E:/www/">
    # Whatever options you need for the common folder
</Directory>
```

This *may* lead to issues with loading assets like css files and the like. This depends on the structure of your sites internal references.

*Note*: if you experience a http status 500 with that ("internal server error") then consult your http servers error log file to find the specific issue. Chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server and the `[END]` flag is not available. In that case try using the `[L]` flag instead.

The rewriting module offers more flexibility than the alias module, but it also adds complexity.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I tried your suggestions, and I got such respond in the browser: `Not Found. The requested URL /project1 was not found on this server.` It seems that Apache `httpd.conf` doesn't allow setting `Alias` to a certain file. Because I tried changing the filenames to paths, then it can work, but not for filenames.

Comment: My fault, sorry. I changed the answer and removed the trailing slash in the `Alias` directive I blindly copied from you :-)

Comment: I just checked again, just to be _really_ certain and yes, this _is_ possible. An alternative would be internal rewriting, but above `Alias` approach is much easier.

Comment: Wow, it works! My problem was solved. Really thank you!! Your answer is just what I want! It's so convenient with just a line of `Alias` setting.

Comment: You are welcome, glad I could be of help. Have a great day!

Comment: I'm curious about how to achieve this in the alternative way of `internal rewriting`? :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152885/discussion-between-benson-and-arkascha).

Comment: There's another issue emerge: although I can set alias as I wish, but it seems that the homepage file can't load the resources (.js, .css etc. referenced in relative paths) any more.

Answer (score 1):

mod_alias

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html

You can use it in conjunction with rewrites and LocationMatch directive to achieve all kids of things.
However the word 'disguise' you used makes me think you really just need to read the .htaccess manual:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, you're right, I'm not familar with Apache (sorry for that). I just began to dive into it. I will follow your suggestions and read the docs you posted above.